# I am trying to run two batteries in parallel

Tags: power, current, diodes

I am an up and coming fire hazard, I am trying to run two Ebike batteries in parallel. They both have individual Battery Management Systems. The battery management systems trigger each other if you directly connect them, which is correct.

I want to know if I place a diode inline on each anode (positive side) and run 1 (negative) for both batteries. I included a diagram and the information. I am fresh to electrical engineering. Would a Schottky diode survive this type of use? Am I going about this correctly? (I searched and I don't think I got the clarity I need.)

[image]

Comment: I would try it. But: For every amp you draw, about .5W is lost in the diode! So you will need to somehow cool the diode when drawing more than a few amps.

Comment: The controller will ‘see’ about 1V lower than the true battery voltage because of the drop in the diode, which will be more pronounced at high current.  This may or may not be a problem.  Are you running 2 packs to increase current capability or to extend range?  If the latter you might be better off just switching between the two packs as needed.

Comment: Also if you’re pulling 60A it would be wise not to run the diodes at their max rating, so find some higher-rated parts if you can, 80 or 100A.

Comment: Cooling. My solution was to laminate it between two aluminum cooling blocks with thermal epoxy. I want to connect them to increase range and decrease voltage sag. Voltage sag is a safety concern when trying to accelerate from a stop when at lower charges. I can get an 80amp. At 60A with .5v loss per amp, I am losing 40 volts?

Comment: @frog I just figured out I have to tag you.

Comment: What peak current draw are you expecting (for both  batteries combined)? How do you charge the batteries?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott The BMS is limited to 60A on each battery. So it should only be 60A in total since it's parallel. This is the diode i want to use.https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/STPS160H100TV?qs=JV7lzlMm3yL081IldiNQdg%3D%3D

Comment: It’s unlikely that the BMS will current-limit at 60A, it’s much more likely that the pack will shut down altogether until the load is removed.  If the two packs are at more or less the same state of charge then they are likely to share the current reasonably well but it’s quite possible that you’ll see power cutting out under high loads.

Comment: Regarding the voltage drop across the diode, you may well see 0.5V at 1A but the drop will be only a little higher at much higher current, there should be a graph in the datasheet.

Comment: @ Frog. I believe I have an amp limit on my controller I can set. I found the graph for the diode im going to buy, at 100a it loses exactly 1v, so the losses are zero in my application. I am going with a 100v 80a diode. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/STPS160H100TV/603748

Comment: I didn't tag you correctly. @frog